# Div with columns overlaps elements while resizing

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Okay so i have a div with a container and 3 equal columns inside.Every column has a card with fixed height and width inside. However, below 1200px my design for a reason is breaking. What i mean is that when i resize to 1200px columns start to merge together and eventually in smaller sizes they tend to overlap the div and my footer. I know its complicated so here's some code.

----------HTML----------

```
      <!-- 2nd card -->
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card">
                <div class="cardoverlay"> 
                </div>
                </div>
             </div>
      <!-- 3rd card -->
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="cardoverlay">
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

-----------CSS-----------

```
.categories {
        background-color: #e1e1e1;
        height: 800px;  
    }
    .card {
        width: 353px;
        height: 662px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px/7px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px/7px;
        border-radius: 8px/10px;
        background-color: #fff;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px #b8b3b3;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px #b8b3b3;
        box-shadow:  3px #b8b3b3;
        margin-top: 50px;

    }
    .cardoverlay {
        width: 353px;
        height: 202px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0/10px 10px 0 0;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0/10px 10px 0 0;
        border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0/10px 10px 0 0 #f1f1f1;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px #f1f1f1;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px #f1f1f1;
        box-shadow: 0 3px #f1f1f1;
```

The columns at this point are getting merged. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kvBi.jpg

P.S i am using container instead of container-fluid so i can get the columns the one next to each other.

Comment: Can you post your full code? A demo in Jsfiddle would be better.

Comment: What do you expect to happen? If you specify custom width, bootstrap will keep it and therefore not shrink below it (merging your columns before switching to mobile mode). If you don't then it will resize just fine and  will switch to full width mode, placing them underneath each other on mobile mode.

Comment: That's because you've set a `width` property with a defined value in pixels? It's never going to get smaller than that because that's how wide you've said you want it to be. Use `%` in oppose to `px` and it should become fluid. Use `max-width` if you need it to stop getting bigger at a particular size!

Comment: Yes but if i dont specify the height and width of my cards how would they show?? I mean that i should specify size for my cards, shouldn't i?

Comment: Combine `max-width` with `width` and `max-height` with `height`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a specific width rule, meaning the divs will always stay at those sizes. When the browser is re-sized smaller they will run over each other.

If you use a percentage based layout `%` this will not happen as they will scale relative to the container size.

```
.card, .cardoverlay {
  width: 33%;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that inside the cards i have some text and fixed lines. How can i handle that if i use the above?

Comment: It depends what your trying to achieve. You can use pixels too, but if you're re-sizing the browser you are testing a responsive design, and you should use media queries to change your values at different view ports.

Comment: it would be easier to give you a firm answer if you posted a more full example of your code @user1608946

Comment: You could. The first thing to decide is: Do I want a full-width or fixed width layout? If you want a full-width you will use a percentage based layout for the container which will stretch the layout to always take the full screen or do you want fixed width. If you want a fixed width, you could set a `max-width` for the wrapper and then used pixel or percentage based containers inside that.

Comment: i dont want to take the full width that's why i am using container!

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Wy22s/696/ Please note that inside the cards i am using h2, h3 tags paragraphs and fontawesome icons. I guess i have to use media queries for the text inside!